# Relacionar produtos de diferentes lojas automaticamente

Tags: c#, sql, string

Estou com uma dúvida em comparar preços de produtos de diferentes lojas, não tenho ideia de qual componente utilizar ou como fazer isso. A ideia é fazer algo parecido com Buscapé e Zoom (relacionar o mesmo produto em diferentes lojas), e , posteriormente utilizar esse relacionamento para calcular a media de preço do produto no mercado e-commerce. Eu insiro os dados dos produtos (ID, Nome, Valor) das lojas no banco (SQL Server) mas não tenho ideia de como relaciona-los de maneira automática.

Acredito que seja por string, porém, pode existir produtos com nome cognatos mas diferentes.

Exemplo:

> Smartphone Dual Chip Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini Duos Desbloqueado Preto
>   Android 4.2 3G/Wi-Fi Câmera 8MP 8GB
>
> Samsung Galaxy S4 Active Desbloqueado Grafite Android 4.2 4G/WiFi
>   Câmera de 8MP 16GB
>
> Smartphone Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom Branco Android 4.2 3G Desbloqueado -
>   Câmera 16MP Câmera Wi-Fi GPS Memória 8GB

O único modo de relacionar o mesmo produto de diferentes lojas é manualmente? Ou existe algum componente que possa utilizar para automatizar essa função?

Comment: Muito provavelmente, se você tiver algum site desses de sucesso, consegue negociar com as lojas alguma API para atualizar os dados (afinal, o interesse é deles). Você pode até fazer o _parse_ de páginas do site, porém tem que estar preparado para mudanças, e ter um alerta para quando algo muda. Definitivamente não é bom para quase todos os casos. O caminho da API é o caminho limpo pra isso. Inclusive, você pode fazer a API do seu lado e disponibilizar para as próprias lojas se tiver um bom representante pra convencê-las a usar (e um belo contrato pra que eles publiquem o preço correto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende do tipo de informação que as lojas te passarem. Existem algumas informações que são únicas de produto para produto, independente do lugar que a vende.

Esse tipo de classificação é bem comum quando se trabalha com supply chain, uso de SKUs, etc.

Se você conseguir obter o código de barras de cada produto, é muito provável que você conseguirá relacionar um produto com outro de outras lojas e garantir que será o mesmo produto. Acho que essa seria a maneira mais fácil de conseguir, mas tem que garantir que as lojas forneçam essa informação para você.

Comment: Rodrigo, eu consigo o nome e ID do Produto (SKU), mas para cada loja é diferente . Gostaria de saber como os comparadores de ofertas relacionam os produtos, como por exemplo o econovia.com.br que utiliza "scrape" de paginas para popular a base de dados. Realmente, me ajudaria muito descobrir como é feito esse relacionamento.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates os donos de loja podem classificar seus produtos com código próprios. Mas itens de venda para o consumidor final utilizam um código de barras universal, que identificam o país de origem, o nome da empresa, modelo e um produto único daquele modelo. este é o código que vem na caixa de cereal, na caixa da TV etc. Pode ser que a API da loja esteja te mandando o interno e não esse. Esse você pode buscar até pelo Google.

Comment: @JeanGustavoPrates vou dar um exemplo.. O submarino tem uma API em JSON que voce pode obter os produtos e este lhe retorna uma lista de SKUs. Voce pode perguntar por cada SKU e neles, vai obter uma informação de EAN. EAN e um destes padrões internacionais para identificar um único produto. Com ele, voce pode relacionar produtos de EAN igual de outras lojas sem medo! https://api-marketplace.submarino.com.br/explorer/#!/v1/sku/getSku_get_1

Comment: Obrigado, vou estudar!